# Is it possible to edit a Gradient Swatch in Illustrator's UI?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, gradient, illustrator-scripting, swatches

I can't find any way to edit a Gradient Swatch in Illustrator's UI. I can do lots of things with a Color Swatch or a Pattern Swatch, but for some reason, I can only change the name of a Gradient Swatch when I double-click on it in the Swatches panel. If you "edit" it with the Gradient panel, that creates a brand new Gradient that you'll have to add to the Swatches, NOT the original Gradient at all. I tried using a script and it worked, but that's such an ass backward way to go about it. There's [this uservoice request](https://illustrator.uservoice.com/forums/333657-illustrator-desktop-feature-requests/suggestions/33164479-make-gradient-swatches-global) from 2018 that kind of confirms my suspicion that it's impossible, because I reckon the only reason Adobe assumes you'd want to edit a Gradient Swatch is to make it global.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can <kbd>alt</kbd> + **drag** the swatch from the gradient panel (or object color) into your existing swatches. You have to be a bit careful with this so you actually drag on the swatch not between the swatches.

And yes swtached gradients are global. Same works for patterns too.

Comment: I suppose this works. Still have to add a new swatch tho.

Comment: @Vun-HughVaw no you dont need to make a new one. You can alt+drag directly from the gradient window prewiew, color window or toolbox to overwrite the old one. Just as long as you hold down alt before starting the drag